# IO EXCEPTION importing local .vcf file in android

Tags: android, import, vcf-vcard

I'm devoloping an app on Android 2.3.3 that needs to import a local .vcf file.
I try to import it launching the intent

```
final String pathDownload = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/vcard1.vcf";

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pathDownload), "text/x-vcard");
    activity.startActivity(i);
```

But this causes an IOException even if the file exists and it can be easily
imported from any filemanager. Any ideas?

```
07-26 12:10:04.995: I/ActivityManager(307): START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf typ=text/x-vcard flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.vcard.ImportVCardActivity u=0} from pid 7681
07-26 12:10:05.050: I/ActivityManager(307): START {cmp=com.android.contacts/.vcard.SelectAccountActivity u=0} from pid 7604
07-26 12:10:05.057: I/SelectAccountActivity(7604): The number of available accounts: 2
07-26 12:10:05.057: I/AccountSelectionUtil(7604): The number of available accounts: 2
07-26 12:10:10.065: I/ActivityManager(307): Displayed com.android.contacts/.vcard.SelectAccountActivity: +5s15ms (total +5s26ms)
07-26 12:10:19.190: I/VCardImport(7604): Starting vCard import using Uri /storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf
07-26 12:10:19.198: I/VCardImport(7604): Bind to VCardService.
07-26 12:10:19.307: I/VCardImport(7604): Connected to VCardService. Kick a vCard cache thread (uri: [/storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf])
07-26 12:10:19.307: I/VCardImport(7604): vCard cache thread starts running.
07-26 12:10:19.315: I/VCardImport(7604): Copy a Uri to app local storage (/storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf -> import_tmp_0.vcf)
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604): IOException during caching vCard
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:708)
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:612)
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:447)
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604):    at com.android.contacts.vcard.ImportVCardActivity$VCardCacheThread.copyTo(ImportVCardActivity.java:392)
07-26 12:10:19.315: E/VCardImport(7604):    at com.android.contacts.vcard.ImportVCardActivity$VCardCacheThread.run(ImportVCardActivity.java:300)
07-26 12:10:19.315: I/VCardImport(7604): Finished caching vCard.
07-26 12:10:19.339: I/ActivityManager(307): Displayed com.android.contacts/.vcard.ImportVCardActivity: +14s303ms
```

UPDATE:Changing the Intent to:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   Uri.parse(pathDownload));
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     i.setType("text/x-vcard");
     activity.startActivity(i);
```

I can import any 2.1 vcf file. But if I try the same with a 3.0 vcf here's what's happens:

```
07-26 15:55:40.783: I/VCardImport(2453): Bind to VCardService.
07-26 15:55:40.923: I/VCardImport(2453): Connected to VCardService. Kick a vCard cache thread (uri: [file:///storage/sdcard0/Podcasts/vcard1.vcf])
07-26 15:55:40.923: I/VCardImport(2453): vCard cache thread starts running.
07-26 15:55:40.931: I/VCardImport(2453): Copy a Uri to app local storage (file:///storage/sdcard0/Podcasts/vcard1.vcf -> import_tmp_1.vcf)
07-26 15:55:40.939: W/vCard(2453): Property name unsupported by vCard 2.1: N
07-26 15:55:40.939: W/vCard(2453): Property name unsupported by vCard 2.1: ORG
07-26 15:55:40.947: W/vCard(2453): The value unsupported by TYPE of 1: 
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453): Maybe the file is in wrong format
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453): com.android.vcard.exception.VCardException: Space exists at the beginning of the line
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParserImpl_V30.getNonEmptyLine(VCardParserImpl_V30.java:124)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParserImpl_V21.parseItem(VCardParserImpl_V21.java:306)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParserImpl_V21.parseItems(VCardParserImpl_V21.java:289)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParserImpl_V21.parseOneVCard(VCardParserImpl_V21.java:226)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParserImpl_V21.parse(VCardParserImpl_V21.java:932)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.vcard.VCardParser_V30.parse(VCardParser_V30.java:87)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.contacts.vcard.ImportVCardActivity$VCardCacheThread.constructImportRequest(ImportVCardActivity.java:478)
07-26 15:55:40.955: E/VCardImport(2453):    at com.android.contacts.vcard.ImportVCardActivity$VCardCacheThread.run(ImportVCardActivity.java:339)
07-26 15:55:40.955: I/VCardImport(2453): Finished caching vCard.
```

The manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: can post value of `pathDownload`

Comment: final String pathDownload = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/vcard1.vcf";

Comment: Have you got any solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/sdcard0/vcard1.vcf
```

it clearly says File is not available

and have you given **permission** in manifest file ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: The file exists, infact new File(pathdownload).exist() always return true. In the manifest I have the following permissions:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

Comment: is there any folder in your sdcard named **sdcard0** ?

Comment: the path of the vcf is correct, i get it through:  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()